# "Dependency is not satisfiable" error when trying to install an application

Tags: software-installation, repository, synaptic

When I try to install glchess in Synaptic

[image: glchess install]

I get this error
[image: error]

At a certain time I installed the Gnome desktop and a lot of games that came with it and then uninstalled the games. Now I want chess back. 
When I downloaded the deb file and tried to  install it in Gdebi I got a similar error:
[image: install error glchess]

What should I change in repositories?

Comment: can you pastebin.com the output of `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` as well as `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3DFQ9uGC

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your pastebin it looks very much like you have not got the updates repository enabled

[image]

Tick this option shown - the refresh your installation before install pyChess

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: indeed it was not checked !! (i guess i was trying to avoid the the repeated upgrade announcements). thank you. maybe question should be edited to become more inclusive and useful

Comment: by the way, may i know what image editor you used to create your illustrative image above?

Comment: @cipricus He probably used shutter - its in the repositories.

Comment: its a screengrab from `shutter`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep glchess
```

Comment: would that work for other programs? i got my answer for this one but now i have a similar issue with installing a dictionary (ubuntudico), which i cannot install from deb because of a similar error

Comment: It worked for me while I was having having the similar situation. Maybe it can work

Comment: for ubuntudico2 it doesn't work. for chess i already solved it as seen in another answer