# “Dependency is not satisfiable” error when trying to install ubuntudico

Tags: installation, repository, dictionary

I try to install the ubuntudico dictionary. I found it [here](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/ubuntudico). Downloaded the deb  from the link provided there. I get an error (similar to the one I posted in a [separate question](https://askubuntu.com/q/115694/47206) that maybe could be unified with this one).

[image: “Dependency is not satisfiable” error when trying to install ubuntudico]

What is it to be done? What should I add to the repository?

When trying to install gambas2-gb-qt-kde i get the following:
[image]

I don't seem to find kdelibs4c2a for my architecture. I have Xubuntu 11.10. Universe is enabled.

At [this page](http://laugier.site90.com/ubuntuDico/) I found that the requested environment is:

(k)(edu)Ubuntu 8.04 and above

Debian 5.0.4 and above

(Does this means that the dictionary is accessible only from kubuntu/edubuntu?)

And that the needed dependencies are:

gambas2-runtime (>= 1.9.48)

gambas2-runtime (<< 2.90)

gambas2-gb-qt (>= 1.9.48)

gambas2-gb-qt (<< 2.90)

gambas2-gb-form (>= 1.90.1)

gambas2-gb-form (<< 2.90.0)

gambas2-gb-net (>= 1.9.48)

gambas2-gb-net (<< 2.90)

gambas2-gb-qt-kde (>= 1.9.48)

gambas2-gb-qt-kde (<< 2.90)

gambas2-gb-qt-kde-html (>= 1.9.48)

gambas2-gb-qt-kde-html (<< 2.90)

But gambas2-gb-qt-kde and gambas2-gb-qt-kde-html are not available in Synaptic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the package gambas2-gb-qt-kde has been [removed from the repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gambas2-gb-qt-kde) starting in Oneric. It is still available for Natty and you may get some results by installing the Natty Universe repository and installing it from there. I went and did that and I found that one of the dependencies depends on something from natty main as well, so you'll need to add the following four items to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted
```

Then you'll download the deb for ubuntudico2 from the link you provided and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg -i ubuntudico2.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And then it will install. I would recommend removing the extra natty repos after that to prevent issues with packages later on.

Answer (score 1):

It is along the same lines as your last question. Last time, you needed to enable a repository in order for apt to find the package needed. Think of a repository as a large phone book for programs (which are placed in bundles called packages). What apt is telling you is that it cannot find the package in any of the repositories it is aware of.

There are two ways to fix this. Either install a repository that has that package (if you are aware of one) or find the package on your own and install it.

Doing as search at http://packages.ubuntu.com indicates that the needed package is in the `universe` repository for several versions of Ubuntu [(here)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=gambas2-gb-qt-kde). You can either download it from there or enable the universe repository in the same way you enabled the repository from the other question.

Using a repository is preferred, because you get automatic updates.

Comment: Universe was enabled in Synaptic/Settings/Repositories/Ubuntu Software. I have a general idea on repositories etc, maybe you would guide me a few more steps, as I assume I need a certain version (that is at least 1.9.48) of 'gambas2-gb-qt-kde'. But I cannot find it in the list to install when I put 'gambas' in Synaptic. At the address you gave me there seems to be no version of that one for Oneiric (I have Xubuntu 11.10) but anyway I tried the Lucid version as well as others I found searching and all give me another similar error concerning kdelibs4c2a (>= 4:3.5.9). I added screenshot of that.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I think your problem is that you have an XFCE based desktop but are attempting to install KDE oriented front end programs (see all the references to qt, kde, k-whatever). You might want to consider installing KDE as an alternative to XFCE (you can switch at login) and see if that satisfies your dependencies.

Comment: In fact, I would bet that all of the needed packages are located in the same repository that likely wasn't installed in Xubuntu but is in Kubuntu. Try to see if you can get a copy of `/etc/apt/sources.list` from Kubuntu and compare with your own.

Comment: i do have kde installed thanx - i'll try that

Comment: All packages available using any desktop environment are available with the next one, you dont need to install KDE to install KDE software in Xfce, if the software needs it will pull the correct dependencies. Please don't ask a user to install KDE to satisfy a package dependency.

Comment: I offered it as a suggestion since I wasn't 100% sure it would solve the problem, if you notice my second comment I was pointing out that Kubuntu might have a different list of Repos than Xubuntu. This is really what I was investigating. As you said the package system should fetch whatever it needs, *provided it knows where to find it*

Comment: @BrunoPereira, OP states that the requested environment to run the software by the devloper is [(K)(Ed)]ubuntu, so there might be a reason for that, i.e., there is a different set of preloaded repo sources.

Comment: The repos are the same, there is no separate repo for kubuntu/xubuntu/ubuntu, only different installed default packages, when you install something in Xfce it should be installed the same for any other desktop environment while using Ubuntu's repos, they are the same. The dependency fail will be the same no matter what desktop you are using.

Comment: Then that should be experimentally verifiable. I don't have at my disposal each of these variants of the distribution, hence why I requested either experimental verification (i.e., try on each system) or theoretical verification (I see the same sources.list from each, therefore I theorize it should have the same results). What I'd like to understand is why you're digging up and old thread and arguing that an *investigation towards a solution* is not a *fully qualified solution* by itself.

Comment: I did some research on my own box (which I will now have to revert) and came up with a *fully qualified* solution and I have posted that as a second solution.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency is not satisfiable see : http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=6850971#p6850971

Thanks
Salamandre

Comment: The answer should at least contain  the essential points of the thread linked. Furthermore the link is in french.